# OrphanRemoval gives TransientObjectException:" object references an unsaved transient instance" even though cascadeType All

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've read answers to many of the similar questions on this exception, but most of them seem to be missing CascadeType.PERSIST/ALL. In my case this CascadeType is present.

I have tried a little back and forth, and everything works if the `orphanRemoval = true` is not present in the OneToMany-setting. But we need error incidents to be deleted if removed from ApplicationState.

Minified example:

```
public class ApplicationState implements Persistable<UUID>

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "owningApplicationState",
        orphanRemoval=true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<ErrorIncident> errorIncidents = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addErrorIncident(ErrorIncident errorIncident) {
        errorIncident.setOwningApplicationState(this);
        errorIncidents.add(errorIncident);
    }
}

public class ErrorIncident implements Persistable<UUID> {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "APPLICATION_STATE_GUID", 
        referencedColumnName = "GUID", 
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_ERROR_INCIDENT_APP_STATE"))
    private ApplicationState owningApplicationState;
}
```

The exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing: sb1.vo.creditcard.acscore.domain.application.ErrorIncident
```

This occurs when doing:

```
applicationState.addErrorIncident(new ErrorIncident());
applicationStateRepository.saveAndFlush(applicationState);
```

No deleting involved. Adding orphanRemoval caused the exception to occur while just normal creation of error incidents.

Comment: Please post some code where you are deleting the mapped child entities.

Comment: There is no deleting involved when getting the exception. I have updated the question with this information.

Comment: Why would you cascade from child to parent? Should deleting an `ErrorIncident` delete the entire `ApplicationState` as well?

Comment: No, this is not my intention. I removed the cascading from the ManyToOne in ErrorIncident now, but the exception still occurs.

Comment: I just tested your code with simple id generation strategy as `GenerationType.AUTO` and its working fine.

Comment: If I added entityManager.persist(application) before the repository.saveAndFlush(application), everything worked as expected. What is different when doing persist on entityManager opposed to saving on the repository?

Comment: the code for save and saveAndFlush is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/f202adc7b68acc1c5b39bcdc6ca369d7733a4d14/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L503

Comment: How does the mapping of ids look like?